# Simulate throwing an exception that is package protected

Tags: java, unit-testing, exception

Problem: for one of my unit-tests, I want to simulate throwing an exception (`io.netty.handler.timeout.TimeoutException`) in combination with Mockito. However, Java won't allow this because the exception is package-protected.

Right now I have the following bit of code:

```
doAnswer(invocation -> {
            throw new TimeoutException("test-description");
        }).when(someObject).someMethod();
```

This bit of code does not compile, but I would like to know if there are any alternatives for simulating throwing this exception.

Comment: Are you catching that exception in your code that you want to test? Or why exactly do you want to throw it?

Comment: https://netty.io/4.0/api/io/netty/handler/timeout/TimeoutException.html is listed public... Or try a subclass e.g. ReadTimeoutException

Comment: @Lino I would like to test a retry mechanism that I use to perform requests. The retry mechanism can throw a `TimeoutException`, which is caught by a `Fallback` object somewhere else and then translated to another (custom) exception.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The class `io.netty.handler.timeout.TimeoutException` itself is public, but its constructors are package-private. You can mock the exception:

```
doThrow(TimeoutException.class).when(someObject).someMethod();
```

or:

```
doThrow(mock(TimeoutException.class)).when(someObject).someMethod();
```